# Elasticsearch bool filter and minimum_should_match option

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a following situation - I need to change my bool query to a filter in order to check if it's faster. 
Problem is, we use `minimum_should_match` parameter a lot, typically with 1 or 0 as a value. Bool filter does not support `minimum_should_match`, apparently - it gives me `nested: QueryParsingException[[index_name] [bool] filter does not support [minimum_should_match]` error. So what do I do? Are there any workarounds? 
We use Elasticsearch 1.7.1

Comment: Can you please link the doc where it says that it is not supported?

Comment: @MarioTrucco my mistake - read it in https://www.manning.com/books/elasticsearch-in-action

Comment: and there it is from my server - `nested: QueryParsingException[[index_name] [bool] filter does not support [minimum_should_match]`

Comment: Yes, I tried it too and got the same. I didn't know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your typical situation you don't need `minimum_should_match`.

This may not completely answer your question since it is a solution only for `0` and `1`.

I wasn't aware that it isn't supported; however, notice that for `1` and `0` you don't need the option, because 1 is the default value, and 0 is invalid; it gets ignored and it is as if it were 1. From the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html):

> No matter what number the calculation arrives at, a value greater than the number of optional clauses, or a value less than 1 will never be used. (ie: no matter how low or how high the result of the calculation result is, the minimum number of required matches **will never be lower than 1** or greater than the number of clauses.

Comment: ok, so we can safely update to using filters, I guess. thanks

Comment: Yes, after removing useless minimum_should_match. I would however question what was the expected behavior (especially when you used 0)